# Changing Windows Domain UserName

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain, exchange-2003, user-accounts

i have a small network thats managed by a windows server 2003 box with active directory and microsoft exchange. I want to rename my username but want to know if anything is going to be affected by it.

Specially. do i have to make any changes to exchange? is it as simple as changing the name, logging off and logging back on again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exchange will take care of itself. File and Folder permissions will remain intact and will reflect the new username. Profile folders will retain the old username.

Comment: Uh.... what he said. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your account name will change but not your SID, files and folders permissions won't change nor your exchange mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

scripts that use %USERNAME% could fail but I expect you would already know about those if you had written any

Answer (score 1):

Just remember to add an alias from the old username to the new, assuming you want that to happen. I'm pretty sure that doesn't happen on its own.